# Pipelinedb: How to group stream data by each N minutes in continuous view

Tags: pipelinedb

How to group data from pipelinedb's `stream` by each N minutes in `continuous view` select?

Pipelinedb's stream gets data about the events that comes from a many remote hosts. I need to group this events by type, ip and time intervals in 5 minutes, for example, and count them.

So on input I have (very roughly):

```
time  | ip               | type      
------------------------------------
22:35 | 111.111.111.111  | page_open <-- new interaval, ends in 22:40
22:36 | 111.111.111.111  | page_open
22:37 | 111.111.111.111  | page_close 
22:42 | 111.111.111.111  | page_close <-- event comes in next interval, ends in 22:45
22:42 | 222.111.111.111  | page_open 
22:43 | 222.111.111.111  | page_open
22:44 | 222.111.111.111  | page_close 
22:44 | 111.111.111.111  | page_open
```

And what must be in continuous view select:

```
time  | ip               | type       | count
---------------------------------------------
22:40 | 111.111.111.111  | page_open  | 2
22:40 | 111.111.111.111  | page_close | 1
22:45 | 111.111.111.111  | page_open  | 1
22:45 | 111.111.111.111  | page_close | 1
22:45 | 222.111.111.111  | page_open  | 2
22:45 | 222.111.111.111  | page_close | 1
```

p.s.
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `date_round(column, interval)` [0] function for that. For example,

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW bucketed AS
  SELECT date_round(time, '5 minutes') AS bucket, COUNT(*)
    FROM input_stream GROUP BY bucket;
```

[0] http://docs.pipelinedb.com/builtin.html?highlight=date_round

Comment: After a month of suffering, it works as I needed. I love you.